# Trying to convert influxdb timestamp in a csv to date and time columns

Tags: python, datetime, influxdb

I am migrating an InfluxDB database to mySQL. I have managed to export the influx data to a CSV file, which is great, but now I am stuck with the date and time field which has been given to me.

I have no idea what format it is in, after doing some research it tells me that it is in epoch time, but using python to try and convert the timestamp to an ISO format, it isn't recognised as a valid timestamp. Any idea how to get this converted. Ideally to separate date and time columns. The data that I have got is something like this :

```
time,absoluteHumidity
1578152602608558363,5.788981747966442
1578152608059500073,4.769760557208695
1578152613662193439,5.788981747966442
```

And the python that I was using to try and convert it, was this :

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone


print (datetime.fromtimestamp(1578152602608558363, timezone.utc))
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [influxdb docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#can-i-identify-write-precision-from-returned-timestamps) they store timestamp values with nanoseconds precision.

However the `datetime.fromtimestamp` method expects a floating point number and its integer part is in second precision.

So generally your approach is right you just need to divide the influx timestamp by `1e9` and it should just work:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(1578152602608558363 / 1e9, timezone.utc))
```